# Using native C++ libraries on Hololens (Unity3D)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, dll, hololens

for a different project I am trying to get a native C++ library (libsvm.dll) running on a Microsoft Hololens in a Unity Project.

To try and understand how using native dll's should work, I followed this tutorial exactly:
https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/working-with-native-plugins-2019-3#

When I run the project it works completely fine on my Windows PC, and it also builds correctly for the HL.

But when I try to start the project on the Hololens I get the following error:

`Exception thrown at 0x776E9FC7 (ntdll.dll) in DLL Test.exe: 0xC0000139: Entry Point Not Found.`

Does anyone know how I can fix this? The dll is imported in Unity targeting x86 and the UWP SDK, so I think the Unity side is fine. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After going through this unity tutorial, I find that the project template `Dynamic-Link Library (.dll)` you selected as the scaffolding when getting started to create a C++ DLL in the Visual Studio. If you created your C++ DLL as a Win32 binary, it would throw exceptions when running on the HoloLens2 because Unity will not include standard Win32 binaries when it builds a WSA project. Therefore, it’s recommended to recreate or port a native win32 DLL to the UWP DLL, see the guidance here: [To port a native DLL to the UWP without creating a new project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=msvc-160#to-port-a-native-dll-to-the-uwp-without-creating-a-new-project)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! As soon as I get back to the office I will try it out and then let you know if it worked